# How do I mount an rbd device from fstab

Tags: linux, ceph

According to this link:

http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/quick-rbd/

I can mount an rbd, which works perfectly.  The question I have is how do I do this from fstab?

The end goal being to mount it to `/var/lib/mysql`

I've only found examples for cephfs mounts but not rbd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer my own question.   Which I originally found the answer to [here](http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2013/11/22/map-slash-unmap-rbd-device-on-boot-slash-shutdown/) (just before Noah posted his link to the forums)

Basically the file rbdmap (which I'd seen but not realised it's significance before) is the key to getting it working.

**Note: I'm using ceph-deploy.  That may or may not be significant.**

The init script /etc/init.d/rbdmap and /etc/ceph/rbdmap are the key's to it.

First you need to enable to the init script.  Under Ubuntu/Debian this can be achieved with.

```
sudo update-rc.d rbdmap defaults
```

Then edit /etc/ceph/rbdmap and add rbd entries according to the format given.  By default, the rbdmap file contains:

```
# RbdDevice     Parameters
#poolname/imagename id=client,keyring=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.keyring
```

Enter new entries in there.

For my mysql disk:

```
rbd/mysql   id=admin,keyring=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring
```

And my fstab file contains:

```
/dev/rbd/rbd/mysql /mnt/mysql-data  ext4    defaults,noatime,_netdev        0       0
```

This will be mounted at startup and unmounted at shutdown.  The _netdev parameter specifies that the rbd device will not be mounted until the networking is started and initialized.